# R: Adding Legends to Maps

Tags: r, data-visualization, legend

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to replicate the following stackoverflow post (creating geospatial heatmaps): [r heatmap - stat_density2d (ggmap) vs. addHeatmap (shiny leaflet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749346/r-heatmap-stat-density2d-ggmap-vs-addheatmap-shiny-leaflet)

I simulated some geo-spatial data to match the format of the original data:

```
Lat = round(runif(5000,43,44), 4)
Long = round(runif(5000,79,80), 4)
a <- rnorm(5000,100,10)

map_data <- data.frame(Lat, Long, a)
map_data$Long = -1 * map_data$Long
```

Next, the following code is run to create the entire output:

```
#load libraries
    library(leaflet)
    library(leaflet.extras)
    
#make heatmap for variable "a"
    leaflet(map_data) %>%
      addTiles(group="OSM") %>%
      addHeatmap(group="a", lng=~Long, lat=~Lat, max=.6, blur = 60)
```

[image]

Is it possible to add a legend to this map that shows the "intensity" of the variable `map_data$a`?

I looked at the documentation for this function : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet.extras/versions/1.0.0/topics/addHeatmap

And there does not seem to be an option that allows you to add a legend.

Thanks

Comment: maybe useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011859/add-rgb-legend-to-r-leaflet-heatmap

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! i wrote the full code below in case anyone is interested in seeing the full answer. thanks agai!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestion of @user63230 , here is the full answer:

```
Lat = round(runif(5000,43,44), 4)
Long = round(runif(5000,79,80), 4)
a <- rnorm(5000,100,10)

map_data <- data.frame(Lat, Long, a)
map_data$Long = -1 * map_data$Long


bins <- c(0,1,2,3,4)
pal <- colorBin("Spectral", domain = a, bins = bins, na.color = "transparent")



library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

#make heatmap for variable "a"
leaflet(map_data) %>%
    addTiles(group="OSM") %>%
    addHeatmap(group="a", lng=~Long, lat=~Lat, max=.6, blur = 60)%>%    
    addLegend(pal = pal, values = a,
              title="Heat map legend")
```